# Unable to view user pages.

Tags: bug, status-completed

I am currently unable to view anyone's user page here or on the main site. Whenever I attempt to do so, I am redirected to the standard error page. This has never happened to me before, and does not appear to be a problem on my end. Is anyone else having this issue? Are the SE team aware of the problem, and if so when do they think they'll have it fixed (other than about 6-8 weeks *joke*)?

Comment: Having the same problem. Looks like I will have to get some work done after all...

Comment: Since this has status-completed, I retract my close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're aware of this and working on a fix.

You can see the developer explanation [over here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123891/140548).  Yay leap years! |:

Comment: Wait... it's like the Y2K bug!